# PHP equivalent for Python's protlib

Tags: python, php, binary-data

I've been using PHP's unpack to convert binary data to human readable strings and tried [bitwasp/buffertools](https://packagist.org/packages/bitwasp/buffertools) package as well but neither provide ability to get dynamic bytes.

Is there a PHP equivalent for Python's protlib library which can create objects of binary data with dynamic byte sizes.

For example in python I can use previous input value to get forward `l` bytes here without extra loops or tricks:

```
class A(CStruct)
   a = CUChar()
   l = CUShort()
   t = CString(length = "l")
```

Edit: I'm trying to convert binary data/file to human recognizable strings.

Comment: so you want a kind of Binary to String converter in Python ? like `01001000 01101001` to `Hi` ?

Comment: Here's an explanation of what protlib does: [protlib documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/protlib/). It seems kinda simple.

Comment: PHP does have [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export), [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) and the good old [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize). They let you turn variables into strings and it is easy to turn those strings back into variables. The next step is to make them binary, and PHP has a lot of options there. Combine the two and you're on your way.

Comment: @AbolfazlGhaemi Something like that. But binary bytes `b'\t\x01`. @KIKOSoftware I know what prolib does, I'm looking for something similar in PHP.

Comment: What about [Binn](https://github.com/et-nik/binn-php)? Never used it, so I cannot say if it is any good. It also doesn't show how to get from binary back to something useful, but I think it is possible since there's an "encoder" and a "decoder" in the sources.

Comment: @abhig10 Converting `b'\t\x01` to String is quite easy . do `b'\t\x01'.hex()`